# An expression of covectors acting on vectors on the tangent space of a manifold

Tags: vector-spaces, differential-forms, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. Take $p\in M$ and $(U,\varphi)$, $\varphi:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$, a chart around $p$. Let $\mathbb{R}^n\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right]$ and $\mathbb{R}^n[dx_i]$ the tangent and cotangent space at each point. By definition $dx_i(\partial/\partial x_j)=\delta^i_j$.

I can push vectors and covectors to the manifold $M$.

We define $v=\varphi_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}|_p)$ so that $\varphi_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i})|_p(f)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}|_{\varphi(p)}(f\circ\varphi^{-1})$

We define $f=\varphi^*(dx_j):=\frac{\partial\varphi}{\partial x_j}dx_j$

Do you agree with my definitions? Are this vectors still dual? Is there a general expression for $f(v)$? Is my last question sensible?

Answer (score 0):

I analyses that this post is almost 3 year old but still.

In the answer by [Jesse Madnick](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215206/why-would-we-expect-the-pushforward-to-encode-the-total-derivative-of-a-smooth-m?rq=1) to the fact the pushforward to encode the total derivative of a smooth map. He definition of pushforward as:

$F_*X(f) := X(f \circ F)$

But you define.

$\varphi_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i})|_p(f)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}|_{\varphi(p)}(f\circ\varphi^{-1})$

**First**, where dos the $\varphi^{-1}$ come from ?

It should be simply $\varphi$ from definition.

**Second**, the vector is both the component and the basis.